# Who was the voice actress for GLaDOS?

Tags: portal

What is the name of the person who did the voice acting for GLaDOS from Portal and has her voice been used elsewhere?

Comment: Is this really necessary?  A super simple google search gives you this info without any issues.

Comment: just wanted to share some interesting information.

Comment: We're not really a replacement for IMDB.  Okay, sure, she's a gaming voice actor.  Okay?  We're about *games*.

Comment: If you'd take a look at [**the tour**](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour), specifically the "**Get answers to practical, detailed questions**" part, you will see the first sentence saying: "Focus on questions about an **actual problem** you have faced." I doubt that knowing who voices whom is really going to solve any kind of problem.

Comment: And yet, [questions identical to this one](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=Voice+act) have received very positive feedback, before.

Comment: The top two are the same asker as this question. Way to confuse the asker, guys

Comment: @Timelord64 Those posts are from three years ago.  Perhaps sentiment has changed.  Although, I've downvoted all of them, so I'm being consistent throughout.

Comment: The downvote button says "This question does not show any research effort", and that's the basis for my vote here. Typing "glados actor" into Google brings up several impossible-to-miss text boxes that all list Ellen McLain.

Comment: @JeremyAvalon, Asker answers his own question. One tends to stop researching once they have found the answer they were looking for. No research effort is for posts that ask other users to find a solution, where asker has simply not bothered to find a solution for themselves.

Comment: @Timelord64 The threshold is 'does the question show a bare minimum of research effort', not 'did the asker eventually do any research'. There are two possible scenarios for someone who has this question but not the answer: either they do the bare minimum of research (punch it into Google) and get their answer long before ever getting to Arqade, or they post it here and get downvoted anyway for exactly the same reason.

Comment: @JeremyAvalon, your arguing that asker eventually did his research, but too late. That is not the case at all, considering they posted the answer **at the same time** as posting the question. We do allow self answers, as such, and meta supports trivia questions. Once again, we don't like users asking Google questions, and expecting one of us to Google it for them. There isn't a voice actor question on here that could not be googled in the same way.

Comment: @Timelord64 I'm arguing that the question, in and of itself, demonstrates no significant amount of research. It should be downvoted regardless of whether or not the asker self-answered. I also think you're confusing my argument for downvote as an argument for close.

Answer (score 4):

[Ellen McLain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellen_McLain) did the voices for [GLaDOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLaDOS) and the Turrets in both Portal 1 and Portal 2.

She also did the voice for the following:

- Combine Overwatch from Half-Life 2
- Administrator from Team Fortress 2
- The Witch from Left 4 Dead
- Broodmother/Prophet from Dota 2
- Jaeger A.I. from the movie Pacific Rim

Comment: No. Portal 1 GLaDOS was a TTS which then got added audio filters. Edit: They did this, then got her to imitate that as well as possible. Yeah, this answer is correct but question is not fitting the Arqade theme.